# Unexpected prompt in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this shell prompt
when I'm in the `/home` directory, and how to get rid of it? 
I am using zsh.

I want it to display only the following:

```
user@host ~ %
```

but it displays:

```
user@host ~ (svn)-[jp2014_213276_567222:1] %
```

[image]

I want to get rid of the part from `(svn)` up to the `~`.

Output of `echo $PS1`:

```
%B%F{red}%(?..%? )%f%b%B%F{blue}%n%f%b@%m %B%40<..<%~%<< %b%F{magenta}(%fsvn%F{magenta})%F{yellow}-%F{magenta}[%F{green}2510_1331544_1331256%F{red}:%F{yellow}1%F{magenta}]%f %#
```

Comment: Why what keeps showing? What precise feature of that screenshot do you want to get rid of?

Comment: this right part from user@host ~, so (svn)-(blabla123123) keeps showing when I open /home and before using svn it was normal

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `echo $PS1`.

Comment: Is that stuff at the bottom the response to terdon's request? If so you might want to give it some context, like "Here's the output of `echo $PS1`" or something. Otherwise it just looks like line noise

Comment: Yes that is the output of echo $PS1 and the bottom part of code is the right side of user@host -> (svn)-(name od directory)

Comment: Uninstall Oh-my-Zsh...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've initialized your home folder as a svn repo. Fix with:

```
mv ~/.svn ~/.svn.bak
```

Alternatively, if you're not using svn, you can disable the svn components of `vcs_info`. Add a line like this, after you have sourced oh-my-zsh or whatever:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*'  enable hg bzr git cvs
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `functions`. I'm pretty sure it contains a special function called `precmd` or `chpwd` which sets your PS1.
See 9.3.1 of http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html